# Why does Ajax improve loading times?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, performance

Say you have an `HTML` view, a `CSS` and a `JS` file. In a SPA, you make the `ajax` call and replace the `HTML`, while `CSS` and `JS` stays.

If the page reloads normally, you have to download the `HTML, CSS` and `JS`, but if you have cache active, you'll only download HTML.

**Why is the first way commonly understood as faster?**

I understand there are other benefits on using ajax but I'm wondering about loading times. I feel like HTML parsing, CSS styling and JS compiling may make the greatest difference, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Because grand part of the HTML is actually not changed, so using **xhr** you request only the changed data **reducing rendering time of the DOM**, and since html is anyway more redundant then formats like **xml** or **json**, requesting the data using those formats and inserting them in an already existing **template** is faster in most of the cases.

Comment: Are you sure about this? For example, AngularJS does load full HTML, and for doing the ajax call, even if the data is smaller, you have to grow your javascript with the call, and the methods to print it and add html to it.... Furthemore the data downloading is commonly really fast, it is usually the requests what takes time...

Comment: "...in most of the cases." - Obviously it's based on the proportion of the changed/unchanged content. In case of repeated content (like lists), you could also use client side templating, but there you'll have a **trade-off between bandwidth vs. processing**.

Comment: Yes, but ajax seems to perform much better so I wonder if there is something more important to determine performance. I feel like HTML parsing, CSS styling and JS compiling may be the thing, but I'm not sure.